# Connect with login and password magento 2

Tags: magento2, login

I added a new attribute "login" to my customers. I want to allow them to login with a Username and Password instead of using the normal way of using `Email` and Password.

Comment: This is very confusing...

Comment: why ..?? please

Comment: instead of login with email and paassword he will log in with usernamefor example and password  *

Comment: I'm with you now.

Comment: See my answer. I used this module before and it worked for me :)

Comment: I installed this module but i can't see it in BO where to find it ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest implementing this module to achieve the functionally you require.

https://github.com/semaio/Magento2-AdvancedLogin

**Support login modes are:**

1. Login only via email
2. Login only via customer attribute
3. Login via customer attribute or email

Comment: but when i insatlled the extension i can't see it in BO

Comment: You should find it in Admin area under customer section. If you still can't find it, flush the cache and run the commands.

Comment: Glad I helped :)